# Can a feature comparison question be on topic nowadays on SO

Tags: discussion, scope

This [question Feature comparison of Delphi and MS Visual Studio community edition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27014778/feature-comparison-of-delphi-and-ms-visual-studio-community-edition) was asked today on SO.
The author explicit tried to exlude opinion based answers and recommendations.
 `Just the facts, m'am, no opinions or anything subjective.`
Besides I'd tend to see the as to broad, I would expect it could be difficult(impossible)  to avoid opinion based answers and over the time it might attract other alternatives, which could on a longer run end in a link and spam collection.
The answer got closed slowly which made me thoughtful if my point of view might be to close.
I have seen many well received questions of this kind on SO, but also found many closed as to broad, primarily opinion base or asking for recommendation.
So in agreement with the OP we'd like to get a wider point of view here.

Comment: Seems entirely too broad, given that one is a programming language and the other one is an IDE, which is primarily used for a completely different programming language. According to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23834445/can-i-open-my-delphi-2007-project-in-visual-studio-or-other-ides) VS doesn't even support delphi. Where would one even start comparing? This feels even broader than "C# vs Delphi", which is in itself way too broad.

Comment: Op here - they are both IDEs (Delphi's programming language _might_ also be called Delphi, but it is definitely a feature comparison of IDEs that I was looking for.

Comment: recommended reading: [Gorilla vs Shark](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/08/gorilla-vs-shark/) -- _"if you... don’t want your question to get instantly closed... — try to keep Gorilla vs. Shark in mind."_

Answer (score 11, accepted):

That's a thinly veiled recommendation question.

> All of this makes me want to research the two products and decide it it might be time for a switch.

Even if you narrow it down to two products and ask for a comparison, this is still asking for a recommendation.  Adding "Just the facts, m'am, no opinions or anything subjective, please" doesn't change that.

> Firstly, is there a definite comparison already on-line? I can't find one.

This part of the question is asking for an off-site resource, which puts it squarely in the "recommendation" category.

Comment: let's take the recommendation out (let's assume it would be edited out) I still would assume it would not fit because it would become to broad and attraction opinions and third parties, or is this an overdrawn point of view by me.

Comment: @bummi No, I think you're right. If you remove the request for a comparison already on-line, the question itself is still too broad. It seems like they're asking for a feature comparison between the two, which would turn into a list. This isn't the place to host that.

Comment: OP here. I upvoted this answer, but - the point is that while I agree that a decision will be made, I do not want it to be made on S.O. I want to make my personal decision based on two feature lists. Others may look at the same lists on S.O and make a different choice. The question merely seeks to collect information. Would it help if I remove the two phrases which you point out? I do believe that this could be useful info to the community in general, so long as we can address bummi's (genuine) concerns that it might become opinionated. Surely we can do that by up/down voting and moderation?

Comment: @Mawg No, removing those two phrases won't fix the problem. Gathering up a feature list is off-topic.

Comment: Ok. Thanks for taking the time to reply. I do appreciate the feedback.  Will you close the question, or should I delete it?

Comment: @Mawg I went ahead and deleted it.