# How to flag a question so that it can't be deleted?

Tags: support, vote-to-delete

I just hit my 10k rep, and I gained access to the moderator tools, I took a look around and I found a [question like this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18414012/what-does-angularjs-do-better-than-jquery) marked for deletion.

The question is flagged as too broad, but it has a long detailed answer which I think would be a waste if this question was deleted, if I want to vote against the deletion, what action can/should i take ?

I tried to look around for an answer to my question but I couldn't find any.

Comment: You can vote to undelete as soon it was actually deleted.

Comment: ... which people have been doing back and forth for quite some time now... It's more like a war of attrition than any sane consensus on what to do with the question.

Comment: I see, guess I still have a lot to learn about how things work here, like I said it's still my first day lol

Comment: [revisions history](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/18414012/revisions) suggests that post may deserve content dispute or historical [lock](http://meta.stackexchange.com/tags/locked-questions/info)

Comment: So what's the right thing for ME to do, how should I contribute in handling such a question, just flagging to a moderator?, not just this one specifically, I'm asking for future reference too.

Comment: "viewed 91557 times" - at about 100K views, question may be worth raising discussion at meta. See also [How aggressively should we maintain and improve very popular questions?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/103053/165773)

Comment: Meta SE not Meta SO ?

Comment: meta SO. Popular questions at the site are best discussed at this site meta, for these often involve site-specific norms (eg, tolerance to duplicate answers at Workplace is about 1000 times less than at Stack Overflow)

Comment: That specific question was [discussed](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/277773/popular-helpful-question-answer-deleted-rather-than-locked/277869#277869) before - to make the long story short it was deleted for a reason.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

> if I want to vote against the deletion, what action can/should i take ?

1. Fix the question. That is always, *always* the first action.

Can't fix the question?

2. Try to re-ask the question in a way that fits Stack Overflow guidelines and import over the content. That sometimes means separating a long answer into more small answer and question pair.

Still doesn't fit SO Q&A style?

3. Look around, where does it fit? Tag wiki? A discussion forum? A blog? Remember, that **what you want to salvage is the content**. So long the content is alive, somewhere, and can be findable, you are doing it right. And yes, that means "even if the content won't stay on Stack Overflow".

So, instead of trying to oppose some action you don't agree, try to make the reasons behind their actions becomes invalid (ie. fixing the question) or make sure that even if the question ends up deleted the content is somewhere, which is ultimately what you are worried about, no?

Comment: Thanks a lot, I understand now how I should think about things when considering an action, which was the point of my question.

Comment: For what it's worth this is what I told m59 last time that question was deleted - that it'd make an excellent blog post but isn't a great fit for SS.