# With new knowledge, should I refine my question to make it more specific?

Tags: discussion, questions, edits

I asked a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43690694/2778047) with little-to-no knowledge on bitwise operators. As a result, my question was more broad than it needed to be. Now that I'm armed with increased knowledge of bitwise operators, should I edit the question (and ask the answerer to edit their answer) to make the question more specific, or should it be left more broad?

Specific examples:

- I didn't know about `& 0xFF` being synonymous with `% 256`, and so my question used a mixture of copy-pasted `& 0xFF` and my custom-made `Maths.clamp` function. (I would change this to all use `& 0xFF`)
- Another answer I had copied from added `(1 << 24)` to the stored number, and I didn't realise that it would work the same in my use case without it. (I would remove all of this)

Is editing like this discouraged, as it can affect answers, or is it encouraged, as it makes the question/answers more useful for later viewers?

Comment: No, don't mess up existing answers and don't force a contributor to keep answering new questions.  If you have a new question then click the Ask Question button.

Comment: `& 0xFF` and `% 256` are certainly not synonymous, they behave differently for negative operands.  http://rextester.com/ZXRFLF44031

Comment: @BenVoigt oh, I didn't notice that! Thanks for the tip! Seems to be the case in JS as well, which is what I was using

Comment: WARNING: Risk of Infinite Recursion Detected! :)

Answer (score 18):

Some questions are too broad to be answerable and need to be specialized further, in order not to be closed. Also, as long as there aren't any answers I think it's fine, to modify a question significantly.

However, your question was answerable and was answered in the general sense that you posed it. Please don't change the question anymore because that may actually make the existing answers wrong.

If you have another question that is not already answered by the answers to the general question that you posed, just continue asking. For example, by asking another, more specific question, you could hope for more efficient (specific) answers.

Answer (score 4):

Definitely don't change your question in such a way that it invalidates existing good answers.

If you feel you can re-write your question in a more coherent and more focused way, and that your new question is likely to elicit different answers, then do as Hans suggests, and ask a new question. If you do that it's probably a good idea to put a link in each question to let people know that the new question is a follow-up / reformulation of the old one.

OTOH, if it's likely that the answers to your old question are adequate answers to your new question then *don't* ask a new question, since it will just be closed as a duplicate. In that case, you may like to append some new info to the end of the existing question if you think it may be of benefit to future readers.

Answer (score -6):

> I asked a question which wasn't of enough quality. As a result, my question was more crappy than it needed to be. Now that I'm armed with increased knowledge to improve the question, should I edit the question to make the question more useful, or should it be left more crappy?

Do whatever you need to do to improve the quality of the site, by improving the quality of your question.

Comment: @StephenC wait, we are talking about a question that can be fixed, should those not be fixed if possible?

Comment: @StephenC I do not understand? " If there are multiple Q&A's covering the same material, it is better (for the reader!) if the good ones rise to the top and the rest gently fade away." There's the duplication feature for that, also the site allows for related yet not duplicated content (remember, duplicate questions, no answers). And, who says that all "crappy" questions already have content on the site?

Comment: @StephenC where in my answer we would have N variations of a question? I'm saying "if you can improve the question, you should do so!". You were the one that introduced the topic, not I.

Comment: @StephenC again, where I'm saying "don't delete"? I'm all for deletion, specially if the questions can't be fixed.

Comment: @StephenC How it's implied? If to improve the quality of the site you do whatever is necessary that includes from editing, up to deleting. You are misrepresenting what I said. If it can be fixed, it should be fixed, [if it cannot be fixed then it should be deleted.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/317572/792066) Also see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/287143/792066