# Did we really have to delete good content again?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, deleted-questions, deleted-answers

At [What does AngularJS do better than jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18414012/what-does-angularjs-do-better-than-jquery):

> This is a highly useful question. I understand closing for (some) subjectivity, but did it really have to be deleted? –  Dan Dascalescu

(In the meantime the question was undeleted by consensus). Then after he got it deleted again...

[image]

...Benjamin gloated:

> @DanDascalescu [yes, it did](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/277773/popular-helpful-question-answer-deleted-rather-than-locked/277869#277869) –  Benjamin Gruenbaum

The above link is Benjamin's justification; not the highest voted and accepted answer on that linked question, from which I quote:

> > Incoming questions are a universal constant, all around us in countless billions. But answers — truly brilliant, amazing, correct answers — are as rare as pearls. Thus, **questions are merely the sand that produces the pearl**. -Jeff Atwood, *[Optimizing for Pearls not Sand](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/06/optimizing-for-pearls-not-sand/)*
>
> While this type of question is not encouraged, this type of *answer* is. It is the answer which holds the value here, and simply, blindly, with torch in hand burning it down because of an overly broad phrased question seems to be a little hasty.
>
> I don't think this question should be an example for other questions, but at the same time, I don't think this answer should be removed because it has proven value.

It does seem that [Did we really have to delete this 80-vote community wiki answer after three years?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/286966/did-we-really-have-to-delete-this-80-vote-community-wiki-answer-after-three-year) was not a teachable moment.

For the love of God, if we delete imperfect content, it can never get better. Can we please put a wiki lock on it and let the community clean up the answer?

Comment: Personally I would leave it deleted - for now. Then if we get an influx of questions along the same line we can bring it back, historic lock it, and use it as a target for any duplicates. It's deleted for now but it's not gone, so let's just see if there is a need for it.

Comment: @slugster: how can we see if there's a need for it, when the vast majority of those who need it have <10k rep and can't see it?

Comment: By looking out for duplicates. The reality is that question will have been duplicated a hundred times on the various scraper sites, so I would be surprised if those who need it couldn't find a copy.

Comment: Have you taken any steps to make this content better? If the content had been better, chances are it would not have been deleted.

Comment: @JohnSaunders: I'd love to, but unfortunately Angular isn't my area of expertise.

Comment: Then how can you judge the value of the question???

Comment: I have decent knowledge of it; just not expert enough knowledge to improve the answer.

Comment: Are you finally done with always resurrecting that horrible question? It gets tedious.

Answer (score 16):

In all honesty, [this is a *much* better question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14994391/1079354) to be asking, which is in the same vein as the one in question.

Now, to this question:

[Did you read this Meta post which addresses this very question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/277773/1079354) In particular, did you check out [this answer?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/277869/1079354)

If not, here's a rather nice excerpt from it:

> **That is a horrible question for Stack Overflow.** It is completely
>   subjective, it discusses X vs Y and not solving a specific problem.
>   There actually is a correct version of it discussing the shift from
>   jQuery to Angular in methodology and mindset - this is not that
>   question.
>
> Locking it would make things even worse as both Angular and jQuery are
>   evolving and the answer will get outdated fast. Not to mention it is
>   comparing apples (a library) to oranges (a full blown framework that
>   does a million other things as well).
>
> **These sort of questions are a constant source of misinformation.**
>   They're always too broad, opinion based, discuss off topics and more.

I absolutely agree with the points made in that post above for a few simple reasons:

- Look at what it's comparing - Angular to jQuery.  These are two different entities which serve two distinct purposes.  It only takes a half hour of dedicated Googling to determine the differences between the two.
- There's not much in the way of illuminating fact in the (only) answer that you can't read on the Angular website.
- The question isn't asking something objective - it's very much **subjective** in its intent.

  > I have read a few tutorials on how to use Angular, but I am not clear on why or when to use it, or what benefits I may find in comparison to just using jQuery.

  It's also not just asking about one thing, it's asking about *quite a number* of things, which doesn't mean that the question is focused on a particular aspect.

  > Angular will then provide you a $scope handler, which you can populate statically or through calls to the web server. This appears characteristically similar to JSP way of designing webpages. Do I need Angular for this?
  >
  > Does Angular have any advantages over jQuery or vanilla JS for DOM manipulations?
  >
  > What can Angular do that makes it useful for development in comparison to what jQuery can do along with plugins?

It's ***really*** broad and subjective.  The usage of jQuery doesn't have to be mutually exclusive to Angular, and vice versa.  Whether or not a person elects to use plugins is entirely up to the use case that their code is intending to solve, and there's no magical answer that can satisfy each and every case.

Angular and jQuery have their place in the ecosystem, and are effectively incomparable.  Even the top answer *agrees* that these can't be reasonably compared.

> #### Angular and jQuery can't reasonably be compared.
>
> Angular is a framework, jQuery is a library. Frameworks have their place and libraries have their place. However, there is no question that a good framework has more power in writing an application than a library. That's exactly the point of a framework. You're welcome to write your code in plain JS, or you can add in a library of common functions, or you can add a framework to drastically reduce the code you need to accomplish most things.

**Think objectively about questions that merit salvation.**  I think that, at minimum, a Herculean effort to overhaul the question would potentially keep it out of trouble, but that'd run the risk of invalidating the answer(s) on it already.  I really don't see any sort of copy editing that could be done to save the question with its current answer.

This is not a question to get in a huff about over its deletion.

Comment: "only takes a half hour of dedicated Googling" - at the scale of the Internet, this amounts to thousands of hours wasted each day by those new to the libraries, when they could have read a summary of the differences in two minutes if the question was made CW.

Comment: @DanDascalescu And that would be a good thing. More people need to learn to do their own research rather than having it spoon-fed to them. If someone can't figure out the differences between JQuery or Angular on their own (or are not willing to invest the time to do so) they probably shouldn't be making webapps in the first place IMNSHO.

Answer (score 3):

I should probably wait until the morning to post this, but what the heck?

It seems to me that we have content which is

1. Useful to a certain audience, but which
2. For various reasons we would not like any similar content in the future, for instance:

   - Off-topic content
   - Subjective content
   - etc.

Because the content is useful, there is the feeling that we don't want to delete it.

Because we don't want anyone seeing this content and deciding that we welcome more of the same, others feel that such content should be deleted.

Do I have this right?

Then, as I *know* has previously been suggested, let's *please* move such content "somewhere not here" and then delete it.

The "somewhere" should not be "deleted.stackoverflow.com", since that would suggest that the content is in some way sanctioned. I'd be ok with "donteverpostsomethinglikethisagain.stackoverflow.com".

It would be reasonable to provide links to the new site in tag wikis, and the site could be referenced in answers, but the "useful content" would not be here.

Simply put, it seems that we have useful content that we don't want here. So let's find another place for such content to be.

P.S. I don't care if such content winds up on a variety of blogs. However, the community which finds the content useful might want the content to be hosted somewhere more central.

Comment: ...to [museum.stackexchange.com](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/125172/165773). "This way,

1. Visitors brought by links from external resources would be able to view the intended content.
2. SO quality would not suffer from presence of inappropriate questions.
3. It would be clear that content like this is not welcome at SO anymore...."

Comment: How does your suggestion improve upon the current practice of putting an historical lock on it?

Comment: @slugster I for one suspect that many inexperienced users don't recognize the lock and believe that these are regular, valid questions. "- Why my question is not okay when _this one_ is there? - Look closer, do you see a notice and what it says? - Oh I see now, how could I miss that" -- I bump into comment exchanges like this once or twice a month. I don't even dare to guess how many of them silently think that it's okay and don't ask...

Comment: Yes. This is it. In all these discussions we've had about deleting, no one has ever explained why a question that everyone agrees is not suitable for SO _needs to be hosted there_. If it's so damned valuable, get it out of the hands of these power-mad deletionist fascisti and **host it yourself**.

Comment: @JoshCaswell: because it originated on SO; because SO shows up first in search engine results; because existing links point to that question and deleting it will break them; etc.

Comment: But it appears SO doesn't want this content @Dan. And this time round it appears the majority, for now at least, agree with the deletion. So if you're serious about actually saving the _content_, and not just arguing over the perceived injustice of it having been deleted in the first place, Josh's suggestion is a good one (you could of course do both, I'm just saying).

Comment: If the content is so good and so many people want it, Google will find it no matter where it goes, @DanDascalescu.