# Why are there so many upvotes for this question?

Tags: discussion, specific-question

I just came across [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14994391/thinking-in-angularjs-if-i-have-a-jquery-background?rq=1) which is asked by some senior member of this community. While the question is nicely worded and has some very good answers. However when you read the question second time or if you ignore the upvotes and OP's reputation question seems like it belongs to one of the three categorize "too broad", "off topic because ..." and "primarily opinion-based".

I wonder why the question got so many upvotes (4K+) and so far just two close votes? At the same time what would happen to a new comer if he/she asks today "Thinking in Java, If you come from C background?", or "Thinking in SQL if you have foxpro knowledge".

Is some exception taken by the community for this question or am I missing something?

I believe it has got so many upvotes because it already has so many upvotes and it had so many upvotes from the beginning because OP has so many upvotes.

Should we do anything with this question, and if so, what?

**EDIT**

Based on the discussions that we had here, I found @Frank's answer most complete and satisfying. I accepted his answer here on meta and than I asked [my own version](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31041577/thinking-in-scala-if-i-have-a-java-c-background) of the question in question. However within minutes I was getting close votes. Those who are against the Frank's view can they explain Why my case is different ?

I have spent 4 years here on SO consider the situation for those who are new to community. What message we want to give newbie programmers.

Comment: It has 500,000 views - it likely was featured on some external high-traffic community like Reddit. It has also already been closed and re-opened three times so far.

Comment: It's already been closed [3 times](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/14994391/revisions) and reopened each time.

Comment: _"I believe it has got so many upvotes because it already has so many upvotes and it had so many upvotes from the beginning because OP has so many upvotes"_ - what? No. OP didn't have any considerable reputation (about 1500) when asking the question. Is your question _"Why does it have so many upvotes"_, or _"What should we do with this question"_?

Comment: *"Please explain"* - how? Each person can only explain their own vote, if even that!

Comment: @CodeCaster updated the question

Comment: Is *nothing* an acceptable answer to *What should we do with this question?*

Comment: Hmm. Not saying anything should necessarily be done to it now, but this really seems like a question that would likely have been closed with prejudice, had it been asked by a newb. If I were a new user and saw this, I wouldn't be convinced that the SO community decides on the merit of the question only

Comment: It doesn't, it also decides based on the answers given. And some of those are golden treasures.

Comment: @Gimby well in that case both questions and answers should be made community wiki..

Comment: @Amit Why should they be community wiki?

Comment: @Gimby thousands of Q&A have been deleted by the community ober the past couple of years without blinking even though many of them contained "treasures". I'm *very* surprised a textbook "too broad" question like this made it in 2014 and the asker's rep is the only possible explanation that I can see.

Comment: ... and what point are you trying to make with that? Keeping in mind that this question to has been closed and reopened multiple times, so at several points it already went through the process you are expecting to happen.

Comment: With 7K upvotes, it's clearly very useful to a very large number of people.  With 500K views, it's clearly pulling a lot of traffic to SO.   And whether you think the purpose of SO is to be a business or to help people, the question in question is valuable.   And that suggests that the "too broad" criterion is poor.  Anything that gives people a reason to delete valuable content should be questioned.  I've just voted to reopen.

Comment: Angular was fairly new when that was posted. Any time there is a large amount of information on new technology people will find it useful. As more and more information becomes readily available about Angular that post's growth will wane. In no way should we discourage creating this type of information for new technology - it is one of the aspects of what makes Stack Overflow great.

Comment: You can't have it both ways. Either new users are allowed to ask these questions or we need to close the old ones. A question showing up like this today would be close voted in a couple hours as too broad or off topic asking for an off site resource

Comment: @TravisJ Do the statistics in view and likes support the idea that the post has lost its value?    Should there be an objective metric?

Comment: @DisplayNameismissing Saying we can't have it both ways implies that what matters is the rules.   My view is that what matters is: 1) SO as a source for help for people; and 2) SO as a business.   The rules exist entirely to support those two aspects, not the other way around.  If the rules fail to help SO be helpful and profitable, the rules are wrong.

Comment: @CPerkins - I was not trying to say the post has lost its value. Far from it. I am just saying that there is a bell curve of value there which is probably related to the age of the technology. When it was growing in popularity the front edge was very important and that is where a lot of these views and votes come from I would assume. Has it peaked? Will it take a long time to peak? No. Perhaps. Those would be my answers. Angular is more than likely here to stay and will remain relevant for years.

Comment: @CPerkins - All I'm saying is I see new users ask questions like this all of the time and they get closed... so we need a better way to handle it. "This question has 4k upvotes but my question was deleted" is rough for a lot of people new to the site. Maybe the rules can change =)

Comment: I was attracted to this Q&A by Meta ... didn't notice it before as not exactly my subject ... but by reading it I get the impression that it touches a rather fundamental A vs. B subject, enriched by guidance on "architecture" vs. "programming" etc. As such the whole story is rather enlighting. It seems to show that there is "a market" for such Q&A ...  and I probably may not resist to upvote some inputs as many others before me.

Comment: @DisplayNameismissing I believe that the rules should change, because right now it's easy to show that in some cases, they're in conflict with what at least I think is SO's mission and value.

Comment: @DisplayNameismissing I have asked a similar worded question on a 'new' technology which I want to learn in near future, lets see what happens to this. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31041577/thinking-in-scala-if-i-have-a-java-c-background

Comment: @Pekka웃 - It has so many views because it is the best description of Angular on the internet. It is linked from the official documentation. It is quite a big deal.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

**Lock it**. There are many questions like this, mostly (1) older and (2) "locked":

> [Example from [Python progression path - From apprentice to guru](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2573135/python-progression-path-from-apprentice-to-guru), posted in 2010 as CW]
>
> locked by Bill the Lizard Oct 10 '13 at 11:17
>
> This question exists because it has historical significance, but it is not considered a good, on-topic question for this site, so please do not use it as evidence that you can ask similar questions here. This question and its answers are frozen and cannot be changed. More info: [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help).

This banner clarifies that such questions really *shouldn't* be here. Not a big change, but it sends the right message to the small fraction of visitors who might some day contribute to SO.

Beyond that, it seems like a good fit for deletion and maybe a community-hosted [archive](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/124850/209360), but I can't blame SO (much) for having a policy of keeping these around to harvest traffic.

**Regarding defenses of the post**. Usefulness to the community is not a reason to extend the scope of what's allowed on the SE network beyond Q&A. [Paraphrasing my [recent comment](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/296748/should-a-fairly-off-topic-question-that-would-be-beneficial-for-the-community-be#comment206210_296748)]

SO shouldn't venture into hosting blog posts just because it has a higher PageRank than alternative blogging outlets. Sure, folks will inevitably try to use SO as a blog, but it's not inevitable that it is tolerated.

Comment: The banner seems like a reasonable idea, but I completely disagree about the validity of usefulness to the community as a defense.   Usefulness to the community is why SO exists.

Comment: @CPerkins You see no scope for SO narrower than "things programmers could use"?

Comment: Obviously.  It's not a site about comfy chairs, and I could certainly use more back support.   But although I've been unable to find a concrete mission statement from SO itself, the http://stackoverflow.com/tour page says we're building `.. a library of detailed answers to every question about programming...`.   Not a lot of support for scope reduction there.

Comment: @CPerkins I'm probably misrepresenting you here, but: Keeping up to date on tools is useful, so I should be able to ask "What's new in R 3.2.1?" Using the "right" tool for the job is very important, so... "What is best among X, Y and Z". Learning new tools is useful, so I should be able to ask "I know X, so could you give me your tutorial on Y?" (like the question the OP linked to). Anyway, I don't want to drag you into a long back and forth, but figured I'd explain what I think is out of scope (because it is not a good fit for a finite Q&A...maybe fine for reddit).

Comment: Resolved: no long back and forth.  I expect this is my last attempt at input to the discussion.   You're not significantly misrepresenting me.  I would assert that those questions are all of significant value to the world and to SO as a business (though I'd probably want the comparison questions to be closely monitored and locked when they become flame wars or deviate too far from quantifiable observations).

Comment: This is the best answer.. I hope moderators are listening (at lease the ones I voted for) .... These posts can't be treated as normal posts.. If someone is allowed to ask for such questions than other people must also be allowed to ask such questions..

Comment: I have asked a similar worded question on a 'new' technology which I want to learn in near future, lets see what happens to this. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31041577/thinking-in-scala-if-i-have-a-java-c-background

Comment: I accepted your answer and than asked my own question to see what happens in within 6 mins I got two close votes.. I think that clears what I was asking

Comment: @Frank - If you lock it it can no longer be maintained, and it is very actively maintained.

Comment: @superluminary Yes, that's true. I don't think questions like this belong on StackOverflow, and so don't mind if discouraging new ones (with the banner) also happens to damage the quality of the old ones (by preventing them from being updated). If someone wants to post and maintain articles like this, the web is full of sites that support that.

Comment: @amit - what happened was it got a few upvotes, a few downvotes, and a decent attempt at an answer. If it remains open for more than a few weeks I would wager it would receive several very good answers.

Answer (score 27):

It is a self-answered question, a practice that encouraged by StackExchange.  It does suffer from the typical problem with such Q+A, the question tends to be poor but usually has a decent answer.  In this case the author's answer got bypassed by a much more elaborate answer.  That answer is very popular, usually enough to keep the Q+A alive and get SO users to keep re-opening the question when it gets close-voted.

Why it got so many votes is pretty evident from the view counter.  The Q+A got half a million hits in the past two years.  That's an impressive number, surely thanks to Google ranking it as the top-hit when anybody queried "angularjs jquery".  It is still ranked high but not at the top anymore, Google changed its ranking for SO content in December of last year.  AngularJS has less than stellar documentation but a high "hotness" factor, giving programmers lots of reason to look for Q+A like this.

Not the only example, the next top SO hit in the Google query is [this Q+A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18414012/what-does-angularjs-do-better-than-jquery), much the same in nature.  And the subject of a [meta question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/277773/popular-helpful-question-answer-deleted-rather-than-locked) not unlike this one, SO users bristle when such Q+A gets deleted.  Not exactly the same case, it wasn't a self-answered question so liable to attract a lot more flak.  Like it did.  A moderator cut that Gordion knot by using a historical lock.  Not very appropriate but there just isn't much else available to keep everybody happy.

So, roughly, this is somewhat inevitable.  If the library docs are not great then programmers will solve that problem by themselves.  SO is a logical vehicle, a blog post is unlikely to attract that much attention.  The probable best thing to do here is nothing.

Comment: While the voting here suggests that most people are in favor of leaving things as is, there seems to be no shortage of hate and outrage over that question. In all seriousness, there are far worse questions out there. And it makes me wonder how much of this is fueled by jealousy over the vote counts.

Comment: @Mysticial There's no one vociferously attacking the post here, unless you think I'm a hater based on my answer..? There's no one else even going so far as to say it should be closed. Instead, Pekka and DisplayName seem to be saying that the treatment of the post could be seen by new users as indicative of a double standard.

Comment: You might want to mention that the second one was locked for historical significance instead of left deleted because of those high votes. Either way, it was also closed.

Comment: I already did 20 minutes ago :)

Comment: Also, the second meta-discussion about that second example question you linked: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/287261/did-we-really-have-to-delete-good-content-again For completeness.

Comment: I have asked a similar worded question on a 'new' technology which I want to learn in near future, lets see what happens to this. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31041577/thinking-in-scala-if-i-have-a-java-c-background

Comment: @HansPassant - the reason it gets so many hits is because it's linked to from the official Angular documentation. It is (IMO) the best resource for understanding Angular on the internet bar none. If it remains locked it cannot be maintained, and it is very actively maintained because Angular is a fast moving target.

Comment: You are talking to the wrong person.  I recommended "do nothing" but it got closed and locked anyway.  My powers are feeble, you'll have to talk to @Matt.

Comment: And so it remains closed, Stack Exchange becomes less useful, and something rather lovely dies.

Answer (score -5):

I'll put in a defence for it:

The user is switching from an old set of tools to a new set of tools. Both the old set of tools and the new set of tools has certain properties and intended ways for usage.

The user is thus asking about a high-level description of the appropriate way to use the new tool, especially considering the old routines from working with the old and common set of tools.

Sure this can be broad or somewhat opinion-based, but there must somewhere be concrete design intentions in the new tool that explains why the tool is designed like it is and what would be the appropriate way to use it.

Would a description about usage intentions for a developer tool (that in this case happens to be a framework) really be off-topic?

Comment: A bunch of downvotes but no comments?

Comment: "People need this explanation" is not a motivation to allow such questions which don't really fit the "short Q&A" format of Stack Overflow. It's more something for official documentation or a blog.

Comment: Does it hurt :) ? On meta, a downvote stands for *disagreement*. I've voted down because the question is, if there's something we should do with the question, which you missed to answer.

Comment: @TLama It doesn't hurt, it's just frustrating to see disagreement without any explanation for what lies behind. But now I have some so thanks! My opinion is by the way that we should do nothing with the question because it valuable, on topic and concrete, even if it's more complex than most other questions here.

Comment: I have asked a similar worded question on a 'new' technology which I want to learn in near future, lets see what happens to this. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31041577/thinking-in-scala-if-i-have-a-java-c-background